# How to assert all checkboxes checked in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, assert

I cannot find the right answer, so sharing my code:

```
When /^I should see all of the checkboxs "([^"]*)" is checked$/ do |name|
  a=  all("input[type='checkbox'][name='#{name}']")
  j = 0
  while j < a.length do
      a[j].should be_checked
    j = j+1
  end
end

# @name: the checkbox name
When /^I should see all of the checkboxs "([^"]*)" is not checked$/ do |name|
  a=  all("input[type='checkbox'][name='#{name}']")
  j = 0
  while j < a.length do
    a[j].should_not be_checked
    j = j+1
  end
end
```

This is based on ruby/selenium/cucumber.

Comment: Could you give the relevant `HTML` code to us ?

Comment: What is the problem? What are you getting for result? Also you could try and change all to find and see that you get an ambigous match error so that you have your css selector correct.

Comment: thx very much, I had given up the case.